# Apply filter to the image fragment

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagefilter, sobel

There is a image fragment `A = [7 8 4; 8 6 3; 8 5 1]`, show the result of applying different filter.

1. apply a 3 * 3 mean filter
2. apply a 3 * 3 laplacian filter
3. apply a 3 * 3 Sobel filter measuring gradient in the horizontal direction

And below is my question:

1. sum of 9 pixels is 50, 50 / 9 = 5, so the result of the center pixel should be 5. But what about the pixels around the center?
2. According to the function, it is easy to get the value of center pixel should be `8 + 5 + 8 + 3 - 4 * 6 = 0`, but what about the pixels around the center? Can I just copy the original value, cause I think it is just the image fragment.
3. According Sobel operators, `Gx = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1]`, to calculate the result I need to compute `Gx * A`. But I confused the multiplication. Is that the traditional multiplication of matrix? I don't know how to perform this step.

Comment: There's no "around the centre" in these techniques. They calculate a value for a pixel on a certain location, with a border around it. I.e. only for the centre pixel. So the off-centre pixels will be calculated by a later (or an earlier) calculation, where that specific pixel is the centre of calculation.

Answer (score 1):

All of these are convolutions of an image with a given filter. All of your questions are about the treatment of the edges in the image fragment when performing this convolution.

Pertaining to MATLAB specifically (as your tag suggests), if you use the built in `conv2()` function, MATLAB treats any area where the image and the filter do no overlap as 0's. So your image fragment is padded with 0's.